# Computer refuses to boot from any Windows live media?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-10, installation, bios

I have a Dell Optiplex 760, which is currently running Ubuntu 14.04. I have been trying to install Windows 10 on my computer for days.

I have written the Windows 10 ISO (downloaded directly from the Microsoft website -- so definitely not corrupt) to a variety of media platforms: DVD, SD card, and USB flash drive. My computer refuses to boot from any Windows 10 live media I create, despite all of these devices being prioritized higher than my actual hard drive in the BIOS boot sequence settings.

Yet, when I try too boot from a live USB flash drive containing Ubuntu, it works perfectly.

If it is of any significance, my computer is currently in the AHCI boot mode, out of the following options:

- AHCI
- ATA
- Legacy

So, can anyone help me to identify and address the issue here?

Comment: Since it's a Dell, what happens when you tap F12 while it boots? Do you get to the Boot Menu? If so, does your USB media appear in the list?

Comment: @MichaelFrank
When I access the Boot Device Menu, my USB device _does_ appear on the list, but when I select it, I receive the error: "Selected boot device not available".

Comment: Make sure in the BIOS the settings `Onboard Devices >  USB Controller` is set to `On` and not `No Boot`.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the Windows ISO or its contents to the USB doesn't make it bootable. To do this, you will need the help of some software like [Rufus](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rufus-create-format-bootable-usb-flash-drives) or [Microsoft Media Creation Tool](https://superuser.com/questions/1063467/cannot-download-the-windows-10-iso-x64-file/1063469#1063469).

Create a new NTFS partition which the Windows 10 ISO needs to boot successfully. Boot from an Ubuntu live USB or live DVD and create a NTFS partition for Windows 10 using GParted from the Ubuntu Software Center.

1. Boot from an Ubuntu live USB or DVD.
2. GParted should be installed by default or if not install it using `sudo apt install gparted`
3. Either resize the Ubuntu partition to create free space to install Windows 10 in if you want to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 or else format the entire drive as NTFS. Formatting the entire drive as NTFS will overwrite your existing Ubuntu installation. Follow these steps from the [GParted documentation](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-resize-partition) to resize the Ubuntu partition.

   - Select a partition. See the section called [Selecting a Partition](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-select-partition).
   - Choose: *Partition* → *Resize/Move*. The   application displays the Resize/Move `/path-to-partition` dialog.
   - Adjust the size of the partition. See the section called [Specifying Partition Size and Location](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-specify-partition-size-and-location).
   - Specify the alignment of the partition. See the section called [Specifying Partition Alignment](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-specify-partition-alignment).
   - Click *Resize/Move*. The application displays the resize/move partition operation in the Pending Operations pane.
4. Create a new NTFS partition in the unallocated free space.
5. Click the *Apply* button.
6. Shutdown and remove the Ubuntu live USB or DVD.
7. Insert the Windows 10 installation media and start the computer. In your question you wrote that you have already set the BIOS boot sequence settings to be able to boot from the Windows 10 installation media, so now it should boot successfully.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan, I will try this. I was not intending on dual-booting, so I will just format the entire hard drive as NTFS.

Comment: Be careful to check everything twice before you make any permanent changes to make sure that you don't overwrite any of your stored files.

Comment: This, is actually what I was planning on doing eventually, but I thought the the problem with being unable to boot from the Windows live media was a separate issue, so I wanted to format the hard drive later.

Comment: So, I removed all the Ubuntu partitions, and formatted the unallocated space to an NTFS primary partition. Yet, my computer still refuses to boot from the live media. I receive the same error message, too: "Selected boot device not available".